# Django SortedManyToManyField does not save order in reverse relation

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I am using the `SortedManyToManyField` field from django-sortedm2m as in the following in my models:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from sortedm2m.fields import SortedManyToManyField

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        to="self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="subcategories",
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    categories = SortedManyToManyField(to=Category, blank=True, related_name="product_items")
```

Now, lets create and add some data to both the fields:

```py
# create some categories
c1 = Category.objects.create(name="C1")
c2 = Category.objects.create(name="C2")
c3 = Category.objects.create(name="C3")

# create some products
p1 = Product.objects.create(name="P1")
p2 = Product.objects.create(name="P2")
p3 = Product.objects.create(name="P3")

# add categories to product P1
p1.categories.add(c1, c2, c3)

# add products to category C1
c1.product_items.add(p1, p2, p3)
```

Now, what happens is that the `categories` are inserted and retrieved in the correct order, where as products added to `product_items` are not.

When I checked the underlying **class** type of the field `p1.categories`, it says that its
`<class 'sortedm2m.fields.create_sorted_many_related_manager.<locals>.SortedRelatedManager'>` where as when I do the same for the reverse relation (product_items) it says
`<class 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager'>`

Does this mean that the order is saved explicitly for the field that defines the `SortedManyToManyField` field and not the related_name/ reverse relation?
Do I have to explicitly define the field `product_items` as a `SortedManyToManyField` field on the `Category` model?

I really have been trying to figure this out, but with no lack. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to install and reproduce the issue but I saw two methods on the GitHub repo of the sortedm2m package. Did you try _add_items or set functions? I guess it is a limitation of the package but maybe these functions help with your issue. I'll try to install it and try when I have more time.

Comment: @DenizKaplan Thank you for your response. I have tested the methods you just mentioned, but nothing that works, set takes in a tuple that overwrites all, but it still does not save the order. I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: I think the solution in through model as it saves the the ordering, so i will check that

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy thank you for the follow up, Mr. Mohamed. Do I use the though model on categories field on Product field?

Comment: I've installed and applied your case on an isolated virtual env. With the below versions, it worked:
`Django==2.2`
`django-sortedm2m==3.1.1`

Product (p1) has the categories (c1, c2, c3) and category(c1) has the products(p1,p2,p3). I'm not sure what is the root cause in your case but I guess it is related to migration or package version. Can you share the version of the package and migration file related to the `SortedManyToManyField` field? Did you read the "Migrating a ManyToManyField to be a SortedManyToManyField" field of documentation?